# Robotium - how to run selective test cases?

Tags: android, robotium

My test class has 3APIs that run three test cases (test*******()).
When I run the project as JUnit test case, how stop one or more of these 3 test cases to execute?
Basically, how to selectively run test cases present in the same file? {Putting them in a separate class is not really the solution!! :)}

Rc

Comment: Do you want to exclude one or more of these tests permanently? Or do you want to be able to test just a single test method?

Comment: mix and match, some times include 1 and 2, include 2 and 3 sometimes etc.. Figured TestSuite helps you do that, still investigating. I have different classes with test cases, in the TestSuite, I want to get a few test cases from class1 and a few test cases from class2.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Eclipse and just want to run a single test method instead of the whole suite or the whole test class, you just right click the method-name and choose "Run as.." -> "Android JUnit Test"

Comment: cant0na, need a little more help.
I have two classes that extend to ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 and each of them have three test cases. How do I write a TestSuite (or anything that helps) would run some test cases from Class 1 and some from Class 2.

Comment: @cant0na, how to do what eclipse does programatically. Say how will you do that from suite ? say if i run the test class, it runs all the testcase methods, is there a way to do this elegantly so that only methods which i want are alone run . .

Comment: I'll have a look and see if I have a solution for this.

Answer (score 2):

To selective skip test cases with JUnit you can add an @Ignore annotation above the test method(s) you don't want to run.

Comment: When I try to add a "@ignore", it gives an error, asks me to "create annotation". Help!!

Comment: @Ignore starts with a capitol I. Also, you must be using JUnit 4.x. It will not work with JUnit 3.x.

Comment: Thanks!! But I'm using "robotium-solo-2.5.jar" and "@Ignore" is not working in this case.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this from the commandline:

adb shell am instrument -e class com.android.demo.app.tests.FunctionTests#testCamera com.android.demo.app.tests/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner

In this example, you're running only test method 'testCamera' in class FunctionTests.  You can add multiple values via the -e argument.

Comment: Do you know which are the parameters to get a log as report of the test?

Comment: For logcat, there isn't a way to do so as part of the command to run the tests.  You'll need to start/stop adb logcat in a separate prompt when you execute your tests in order to get the logcat associated with your tests.  Should be automatable with scripts though.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no @Ignore annotation in JUnit 3, I had to figure out a workaround to ignore the long-running activity/instrumentation test cases from my test suite to be able to run the unit tests:

```
public class FastTestSuite extends TestSuite {

    public static Test suite() {

        // get the list of all the tests using the default testSuiteBuilder
        TestSuiteBuilder b = new TestSuiteBuilder(FastTestSuite.class);
        b.includePackages("com.your.package.name");
        TestSuite allTest = b.build();


        // select the tests that are NOT subclassing InstrumentationTestCase
        TestSuite selectedTests = new TestSuite();

        for (Test test : Collections.list(allTest.tests())) {

            if (test instanceof TestSuite) {
                TestSuite suite = (TestSuite) test;
                String classname = suite.getName();

                try {
                    Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(classname);
                    if (!InstrumentationTestCase.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz)) {
                        selectedTests.addTest(test);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    continue;
                }   
            }   
        }   
        return selectedTests;
    }   
}
```

Simply run this test suite as an Android JUnit test.